# ¿Como puedo cargar el activity de Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Cuando abro el programa, la pantalla donde se genera el diseño de la aplicación, simplemente no termina de cargar, y en la parte superior se genera un error que menciona algo sobre un ciclo infinito, pero no se a que se debe.
De primera instancia al instalarlo si servía por completo, pero a la semana empezó a suceder esto. Por favor díganme como solucionarlo, me encuentro tomando clases en esta plataforma y necesito utilizarlo.
Gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado a hacer Build->Rebuild Project?

Comment: Hola no es la Activity es la prevista del Layout @YaremiTorres

Answer (score 1):

Yo también he obtenido este mensaje que no permite construir la prevista del layout :

> Preview timed out while rendering the layout. This typically happens
>   when there is an infinite loop or unbounded recursion in one of the
>   custom views.

Por experiencia Generalmente no se debe a lo que se comenta en el mensaje:

> Esto generalmente ocurre cuando hay un ciclo infinito o una recursión
>   ilimitada en una de las vistas personalizadas.

Al parecer es un error al realizar build o con la memoria, que no permite se muestre correctamente la prevista del layout, te aconsejo limpiar tu proyecto :

`Build` > `Clean project`

y posteriormente

`Build` > `Rebuild project`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o simplemente reiniciar la IDE Android Studio.